# Django NoReverseMatch when using url in a template

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm running Django 1.10 on Mac OS X.

I'm trying to put some links in my templates but I got a NoReverseMatch Error in both templates.

The error looks like this :`NoReverseMatch at /kfet/` with the following sentence :

```
Reverse for 'interface' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id_ienkli': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['kfet/interface_du_klient/(?P<id_ienkli>\\d+)$']
```

Here is the **urls.py** in my app :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kfet import views
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from kfet.models import klient
from django.urls import reverse

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.accueil, name='accueil'),
    url(r'^interface_du_klient/(?P<id_ienkli>\d+)$', views.interface_du_klient, name='interface'),
    url(r'^date$', views.date_actuelle),
    url(r'^achat/(?P<id_bouffon>\d+)/(?P<id_ach>\d+)$', views.achat,name='achat')
]
```

Here is my **views.py** :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from kfet.models import klient,achetables
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse

from datetime import datetime


def date_actuelle(request):
    return render(request, 'kfet/date.html', {'date': datetime.now()})

def accueil(request):
    liste_tokards=klient.objects.all()
    return render(request, "kfet/accueil.html",{'liste_tokards': liste_tokards} )

def interface_du_klient(request,id_ienkli):
    produits=achetables.objects.all()
    klient_selec=get_object_or_404(klient, id_klient=id_ienkli)
    if id_ienkli==0:
        return redirect('accueil')
    else :
        render(request, "kfet/interface_du_klient.html", {'client': klient_selec}, {'liste_produits' : produits})

def achat(request,id_bouffon,id_ach):
    klient_selec=get_object_or_404(klient, id_klient=id_ienkli)
    if id_ach==0:
        return redirect('interface_du_klient', id_ienkli=id_bouffon)
    else:
        klient_selec.acheter(id_ach)
        return render(request, "kfet/interface_du_klient.html", {'client': klient_selec}, {'liste_produits' : produits})
```

Here is my **interface_du_klient.html** :

```
<h1>Bienvenue sur le site de la KFet !</h1>


Choisir un klient à faire payer !



<li><a href="{% url "kfet.views.accueil"%}">Retour accueil</a></li> 

<li><a href="{% url "achat" id_bouffon=client.id_klient id_ach=1 %}">Acheter bière 33cl</a></li> 

<li><a href="{% url "achat" id_bouffon=client.id_klient id_ach=2 %}">Acheter bière 25cl</a></li> 

<li><a href="{% url "achat" id_bouffon=client.id_klient id_ach=3 %}">Acheter pinte Blondi</a></li>
```

And finally here is my **accueil.html** :

```
<h1>Bienvenue sur le site de la KFet !</h1>


Choisir un klient à faire payer!

{% for ptite_frappe in liste_tokards %}
<div class="article">
   <h3>{{ptite_frappe.nom}} {{ptite_frappe.prenom}}</h3>
   <p><a href="{% url 'interface' id_ienkli=petite_frappe.id_klient %}">Sélectionner cette petite frappe</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I believe the `{% url "foo" %}` template tag is effectively a call to `reverse("foo")` .

Comment: How do you call reverse, in which file?

Comment: (thanks for the quick answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interface_du_klient.html` isn't passing a number for `id_ienkli` as required by the definition in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^interface_du_klient/(?P<id_ienkli>\d+)$', views.interface_du_klient, name='interface'),
```

Comment: ok in intergace_du_klient.html there are some mistakes with the second argument because I forgot to remove them sorry

Comment: Sorry for the first post I made some mistakes... I've just modified the interface_du_klient.html file, but I still get the NoReverseMatch Error. As you said yesterday, the {% url 'achat' arg1 arg2 %} is a call to reverse('achat')... Then, how can I fix this error? Where do I have to reverse this url (in which file) ?

Comment: The problem may be that when Django is trying to render `accueil.html`, there is at least one value of `petite_frappe.id_klient` that is null, empty, or otherwise non-numeric, and therefore it can't find a matching definition of the "interface" url.

Comment: It works ! Thank you so much for paying attention to my problem!

Have a good day